# Turning on Teams via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, office365, microsoft-teams

As Microsoft is now moving back to pre-pandemic licenses (Microsoft Opened Teams for everyone no matter their license state.) how can I check what state my E3 features are in? I'm looking for Teams specifically and then how can I enable Teams? I would like to do all this in PowerShell.

Comment: See if this helps: [View Microsoft 365 licenses and services with PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/view-licenses-and-services-with-microsoft-365-powershell?view=o365-worldwide).

Comment: Yes, that is helpful as I am working from the same documentation on getting the SKU. inside the sku are other items like Teams that can be turned on or off. I would like to look per user based on that SKU what the teams setting is for each user.